# Minifying and copying static .js files with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a terribly written library I would like to include as a dependency.

We have to include it manually as a script file, since it has a lot of variables defined at the global scope (talking about `var something = 'something else'` at the global scope).

The library is composed out of 3 separate files that, among other things, share global variables.

There are too many global variables to use Shimming or anything similar..

I really need to run those at the global scope, and also:

- I need to be able to debug these files (not sure if `script-loader` will work)
- This library is huge (~150K lines of code) - so we have to minify it with source maps

The best solution will include a 'vendor' folder with all files minified

Is there a way to do it with an existing plugin/configuration?